# .NET Regex not matching properly

Tags: .net, regex, string

I'm trying to match quoted strings with the literal quote being accepted like:

`"message\""`

`@"message"`

with

`@(["'])[\S\s]*?\1|(["'])(?:\\\2|(?!\\\2)(?!\2).)*\2`

but for

> "message: \"" + message + "\"

the built-in Regex in .NET  matches only `"message: \"` instead of `"message: \""` like it should according to online matchers like:

https://regexr.com/4173n

Does anyone know how to make it work properly?

.NET Code:

```
string pattern = "([\"'])[\\S\\s]*?\\1|([\"'])(?:\\\\\\2|(?!\\\\\\2)(?!\\2).)*\\2";
string test = "\"message: \\\"\" + message + \"\\\".\n";
MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(test, pattern);
```

Comment: To me, this looks like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Are you trying to parse JSON with regex?

Comment: No, its a translation of a huge project. The X problem is: How to match strings with .NET Regex?

Comment: Show the code to repro the issue. Did you use verbatim string literals?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I edited to show the code.

Comment: You did not escape the backslash pattern.

Comment: BTW, [this is your current regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/LtzeS0/1), is the string the one you thought you had?

Comment: You are right! Adding the @ and escaping the backslashes did the job!

Comment: Answer it and i'll mark it.

Comment: Do you mean https://ideone.com/2s1Vku works for you?

Comment: `string pattern = "@([\"'])[\\S\\s]*?\\1|([\"'])(?:\\\\\\2|(?!\\\\\\2)(?!\\2).)*\\2";` is the resulting pattern, putting together the backslash escaping and the @ at the start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You left out a `@` in the pattern and forgot to escape the literal backslash pattern, that must contain 4 backslashes in the regular string literal.

The literal string regex will look like

```
@(["'])[\S\s]*?\1|(["'])(?:\\\2|(?!\\\2)(?!\2).)*\2
```

If you want to use a regular string literal

```
string pattern = "@([\"'])[\\S\\s]*?\\1|([\"'])(?:\\\\\\2|(?!\\\\\\2)(?!\\2).)*\\2";
```

Or a verbatim string literal where you only need to escape a `"` with another `"`:

```
string pattern = @"@([""'])[\S\s]*?\1|([""'])(?:\\\2|(?!\\\2)(?!\2).)*\2";
```

Answer (score 0):

You need this Regex instead:

```
@"^(?<quote>(?<![\\])['""])((.(?!(?<![\\])\k<quote>))*.?)\k<quote>"
```

It does, what you want. matches the qoutes and everything between.

It's actually not my regex, but it Works in your case.

It Works by storing the quote character (either single or double quote) in a capturing Group, then it looks for this, ignoring any escaped quotes.

**Edit**:
If you don't like @-quoted strings, here's the normal string (escaped):

```
string pattern = "^(?<quote>(?<![\\])['\"])((.(?!(?<![\\])\k<quote>))*.?)\k<quote>";
```

Comment: Couldn't make it work, could you show me in an online matcher?

Comment: Beware of the doubled double quotes, they are only needed in code, not in an online parser (beacuse they are used in an @-Quoted string).